# AVPlayer audio isn't always muted

Tags: ios, swift

I want my `AVPlayer` video to be muted unless the user's phone isn't on silent mode. This generally works by default, however sometimes the sound still plays even when on silent mode. How can I fix this? My code is:

```
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: attachmentVideo))
videoView.playerLayer.player = player
player.play()
```

Where videoView is a `PlayerView` defined as:

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

I don't specifically specify anywhere that the `AVPlayer` should be muted...